# How to rectify too many values in subquery sql

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
UPDATE PRE_LB 
SET PR_NPR = 'PR' 
WHERE CIFNO IN (SELECT CIFNO, SUM(LIMIT) 
                FROM PRE_LB 
                WHERE LTWPB IN ('SE','ED') 
                GROUP BY CIFNO 
                HAVING SUM(LIMIT) <= 2000000)
  AND LTWPB IN ('SE', 'ED');
```

> SQL Error: ORA-00913: too many values

How to rectify without using view?

Comment: Just remove `, SUM(LIMIT)` from your subquery. A cifno, e.g. 1, cannot be searched in tuples like ((1,1000), (2,2000), (3,3000)), but only in a list of single values like (1, 2, 3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve this issue with the `IN` operator, ensure that the subquery selects only the CIFNO column :

```
UPDATE PRE_LB 
SET PR_NPR='PR' 
WHERE CIFNO IN (
      SELECT CIFNO
      FROM PRE_LB 
      WHERE LTWPB IN ('SE','ED') 
      GROUP BY CIFNO 
      HAVING SUM(LIMIT)<=2000000
) AND LTWPB IN ('SE','ED');
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a sub-query, you can also use a `MERGE` statement and use the analytic `SUM` function and correlate on the `ROWID` pseudo-column (which is a direct pointer to the row):

```sql
MERGE INTO PRE_LB dst
USING (
  SELECT SUM(limit) OVER (PARTITION BY cifno) AS total_limit
  FROM   pre_lb
  WHERE  LTWPB IN ('SE','ED')
) src
ON (src.ROWID = dst.ROWID AND src.total_limit < 2000000)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET PR_NPR = 'PR';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pre_lb(cifno, limit, ltwpb, pr_npr) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 'SE', 'XX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 'ED', 'XX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 'AA', 'XX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2e6, 'SE', 'XX' FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the `MERGE`, the table contains:

| CIFNO | LIMIT | LTWPB | PR_NPR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | SE | PR |
| 1 | 1 | ED | PR |
| 1 | 1 | AA | XX |
| 2 | 2000000 | SE | XX |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_oIB3QjO)